# How to refresh the text in a multiline textview in android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, textview

I have a textview on the android client to show the status of the server. The status information is append to the textview as

```
logTextView = FindViewById (Resource.Id.LOGtextView);
logTextView.SetText ("Client log:\n", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
logTextView.Append(string.Format("Socket connected to 172.27.27.1\n"));
logTextView.Append(string.Format ("Start send image to server\n"));
logTextView.Append(string.Format ("Successfully send the image to server\n"));
logTextView.Append(string.Format ("Successfully receive the image from server\n"));
```

So it should always add a new line when server status changes. However, the new lines doesn't show up immediatelly but all pop up at the end show when the processes are finished. I have set the `android:singleLine="false"`.

- Can anyone help me change it into a dynamic show TextView?
- Or how to refesh the text in a textview every 1 second?

Comment: You want to append text or reset text? like text view display first connected then Start send image to server.

Comment: Make use of asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You can update the textview dynamically by using timer.

```
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
               //refresh your textview
      }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 10000);
```

Cancel it via timer.cancel(). In your run() method you could use runOnUiThread();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Appending a string to the text view, append the the status to your string and set it as text to your textView.

```
logTextView = FindViewById (Resource.Id.LOGtextView);

String status = string.Format("Client log:\n");
logTextView.SetText(status);

// Server status updated
status.concat(string.Format("Socket connected to 172.27.27.1\n"))
logTextView.SetText(status);

// so on
```